# Get all path variable

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I want to develop a service that return a json file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{fileName}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
public String jsonREST(@PathVariable String fileName) {
    StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    logger.info("===> File name: " + fileName);
    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileName + ".json"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonBuilder.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Parsing: - ");
    }
    return jsonBuilder.toString();
}
```

I need to get the path for example if the json file is in subdirectory or else.

use cases:

- localhost:8080/my-directory/my-sub-dir/my-json-file
- localhost:8080/my-json-file

Would you have any idea how I can get the hole path for example

```
my-directory/my-sub-dir/my-json-file
```

Or if you have another solution to do the same job, I will be very happy for that

Best regards

Comment: Your code is inefficient for various reasons. Why not just return `FileSystemResource` and let Spring Boot do it all itself?

Comment: Thanks @lyubomyr  but do you have an idea how I can do it ? I mean how I can get the path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the full request url by having Spring inject the `HttpServletRequest` and getting it as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{fileName}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
public String jsonREST(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable String fileName) {
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();

    //Do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't need a servlet container to achieve this. If I get what you are trying to do, you want to serve the json files statically. Try tweaking this:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot